# AdMob for Android Compile Error

Tags: android, admob

I am trying to add an AdMob ad to my app. I followed the intructions here: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals and when I try to run it I get these errors:

```
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to    start activity ComponentInfo{com.ComedyZone/com.ComedyZone.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1696)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1716)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:968)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3806)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at com.ComedyZone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1660)
 06-01 19:16:23.337: E/AndroidRuntime(30602):   ... 11 more
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.ComedyZone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockListActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.ads.*;


public class MainActivity extends SherlockListActivity {
public static int THEME = R.style.Theme_Sherlock;
private AdView adView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jokes_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, countries));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

 // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14fc778668df3b");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

    // Add the adView to it
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) {
      adView.destroy();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("Options")
    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_options)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ComedyZone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <activity android:name="com.ComedyZone.Preferences" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: post your code you are getting a nullpointer exception at your MainActivity  line 37

Comment: You've gotten some good answers, but in the future, _please_ debug a little before posting. While we appreciate being thorough, [don't throw a block of code at your readers and expect results](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129787/181088).

Comment: I have spent all day trying to figure this out and I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are you using a ListActivity and you are not using `setContentView(R.layout.main)` your `layout` will be `null` and you will get get a NullPointerException.

See with more attention the example in https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals

one solution is by doing that by the XML.

> Rather than creating your AdView in Java, it's also possible to set
>   one up entirely in XML. To do so simply:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/banner_xml

The problem of not seeing the ads is related to the  minimum size that it needs. The AdMob view should be at least 320 x 50, if it is not, you will never see an ad in your application.

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/intermediate?hl=nl#bannersizes

Try something like this:

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
       <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/home_layout"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <ListView 
            android:id="@id/android:list" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:id="@+id/ad_layout"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="bottom"
                      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/home_layout">

     <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             ads:adUnitId="youaddunitid"
                             ads:adSize="BANNER"
                             android:gravity="bottom"
                             ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, yourphoneid"
                             ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String[] countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.jokes_array);
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries));
}
```

This was tested and it is working

Comment: I replaced:
    layout.addView(adView);
with:
    lv.addFooterView(adView);

And my app now runs but the ad doesn't show.

Comment: are you testing in the emulator?

Comment: set the test mode
`AdManager.setTestDevices( new String[] {                 
   AdManager.TEST_EMULATOR,             // Android emulator
   "E83D20734F72FB3108F104ABC0FFC738",  // your Phone id
} );`

Comment: I set the test mode and tested on both my phone and emulator and it does not work

Comment: I get nullpointerexception error when i try and do it via xml also

Comment: You have added `com.google.ads.AdActivity` to the manifest, right? And the networking permissions `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE`.

Comment: Yup, if you wish I added it above

Comment: @GreekOphion Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2):

`setContentView(R.layout.your_layout)` is missed in your code!!

you get a nullpointer exception when u use

```
layout.addView(adView);
```

try to debug your code!!

ListActivity does not require that you assign a layout to it via the **setContentView()** method, if you only want to show a ListView ListActivity contains per default a ListView.

In case you need to include more Views (that's your case for the ads) then a ListView in your ListActivity you can still assign a layout to your Activity. In this case your layout **must** contain a ListView with the android:id attribute set to **@android:id/list**.

your SherlockListActivity extends from ListActivity i suppose and that's what i said above is what you should take care of!!

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

change `android:id="@+id/list"` to `android:id="@android:id/list"`

list activity use a default id in the android sdk for listviews it's **android:id="@android:id/list"** you have to keep that in mind!!

Comment: I have done that but I get error saying: E/AndroidRuntime(7480): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: yes i mentioned that your list id must be @android:id/list not an id picked from your choice

Comment: Check my main.xml file. I have it set to list

Comment: check my update the id that you should use is the one that i gived to you not a random id that you choose this how listactivity works my friend

Comment: Ok, it runs but none of the list items nor the ad is showing.

Comment: try to comment code from adview = new view... to the end of onCreate method, and tell me if the list shos or not?